# can xsd ensure node count and not care about order

Tags: xml, xsd

I've tried several approaches to creating a schema for this problem, but I haven't had any success.  I'm not really sure if it's possible.

Basically, suppose I have a root node `<root>` and it can have children `<A>`, `<B>`, and `<C>`.

For each iteration of the program outputting the xml, A, B, and C nodes are made and appended as children to the root.  Though, each iteration doesn't always use each A, B, and C... in which case it outputs no node.  So I get something like this as an example:

```
<A>sfs</A> <!-- first iteration used A, B, and C -->
<B>sfs</B>
<C>ss</C>
<A>fff</A> <!-- second iteration used A, and C, not B -->
<C>ss</C>
<B>fff</B> <!-- third iteration used only B -->
```

I didn't write the program that outputs it in this way, and have no real power over the format.

What I do know for example, is there can never be more than 10 A's, 2 C's, 5 B's ever.  Though, the order isn't guaranteed.

So all I wanted was an XSD to determine that there are only A, B, and C nodes inside root and that there are no more than 10 A's, 2 C's, and 5 B's.

I can achieve the first part by using xs:choice and maxOccurs unbounded.  Which guarantees only A, B, and C nodes, but I can't seem to figure a way to enforce the number of them.

Is there some clever workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do to validate this kind of structure using XSD. XSD is very restrictive.

You would probably be better off consuming the xml and then doing some checking on the de-serialized instance in code.